# 'Index' is ambiguius for type lookup in this context

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using two libraries that have conflict to each other:

```
import DropDown
import SwiftyJSON
```

my code:

```
  self.dropDown.customCellConfiguration = { (index: Index, item: String, cell: DropDownCell) -> Void in
                guard let cell = cell as? MyCell else { return }
```

I get this error:

```
'Index' is ambiguius for type lookup in this context
```

I changed `Index`to `DropDown.Index` but I got this error:

```
Index is not a member type of DropDown
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Index` is not a valid type within your module or the DropDown module. Are you sure `Index` exists as a type? Maybe its type `Int` or `IndexPath` instead?

EDIT:
Upon a second look, you can change this so the error is not a problem. In Swift, you dont need to specify the type information here as it can be inferred:

```
self.dropDown.customCellConfiguration = { index, item, cell in
    ...
}
```